# Why are my textures showing up as fractal patterns with my openGL renderer?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, texturing

I'm working on getting textures to render using openGL. I'm part of the way there and stuck.

My goal is to get this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/67lqK.jpg

and this is where I'm at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBkwQ.png

Has anyone seen this issue before?

```
if (tObject == 0)         // We don't yet have an OpenGL texture target
{
    // This code counts the number of images and if there are none simply 
    // returns without doing anything
    int nImages = 0;
    while (tName[nImages][0] != '\0' && nImages < MAX_IMAGES)
        nImages++;

    if (nImages < 1)
        return;

    // To Do
    //
    // Generate a texture object and place the object's value in the "tObject"
    // member, then bind the object to the 2D texture target

    glGenTextures(nImages, &tObject);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tObject);

    for (int nImage = 0; nImage < nImages; nImage++)
    {
        // This code loads the texture using the windows library's "BitmapFile" object
        BitmapFile texture;
        if (!texture.Read(tName[nImage]))
            complain("Couldn't read texture %s", tName);

        GLuint srcFormat, targFormat;
        // To Do
        // 
        // First decide which format the texture is.  If the texture has 4 bytes
        // per pixel then it should be an RGBA texture, if it is 3 bytes per pixel
        // then it is an RGB image.  Notice though that the byte order for the BitmatFile
        // object is reversed, so you need to take that into account in the "source" format

        if( texture.BytesPerPixel() == 3 )
        {
            srcFormat = GL_BGR;
            targFormat = GL_RGB;
        }
        else
        {
            srcFormat = GL_BGRA;
            targFormat = GL_RGBA;
        }

        // Then you need to set the unpack alignment to tell OpenGL about the structure 
        // of the data in the image and send the data to OpenGL.  If there are multiple files
        // then we are manually creating a mipmap here and you will use the "level" parameter
        // of glTexImage2D to tell OpenGL which mipmap level is being set.  The levels are 
        // set in the same order as they are stored in the image list.

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        if( nImages > 1 )
        {
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, nImage, targFormat, texture.Width(), texture.Height(), 0, srcFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.ImageData());
    }
    // Finally, if there is only one image, you need to tell OpenGL to generate a mipmap

    if( nImages == 1)
    {
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
}   

// Here you need to bind the texture to the 2D texture target and set the texture parameters
// You need to set the wrap mode, the minification and magnification filters.

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tObject);

glTexParameteri(tObject, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(tObject, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(tObject, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(tObject, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

// To Do 
//
// For advanced antialiasing set the number of anisotropic samples
GLERR;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the texture is the problem and not for example the texture coordinates? Try to display the coordinates instead of the final color to check if they are correct.

Comment: This ended up helping with my problem! When passing my vertex attributes to the graphics card, I was using the wrong stride size.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the logic you are using to call `glGenerateMipmap (...)`. The second parameter to `glTexImage2D (...)` is the texture LOD - `glGenerateMipmap` will generate *the entire* mip pyramid starting with LOD 0. Essentially, you invalidate every one of the calls to `glTexImage2D (...)` except the first and last iterations of that loop by doing this. It really looks like you either want an array texture, or each one of those images should be a separate texture.

In fact, `glGenTextures (...)` does not work the way you think it does. You are supposed to pass an array if `nImages` is > **1**. That array will hold `nImages`-many texture object names. You bind each one and upload image data individually to LOD 0, *then* you can generate mipmaps.

#### The following addresses everything I just mentioned:

```
GLuint* tObjects = NULL;

if (tObjects == NULL)      // We don't yet have any OpenGL textures
{
    // This code counts the number of images and if there are none simply 
    // returns without doing anything
    int nImages = 0;
    while (tName[nImages][0] != '\0' && nImages < MAX_IMAGES)
        nImages++;

    if (nImages < 1)
        return;

    tObjects = new GLuint [nImages];

    // To Do
    //
    // Generate multiple texture objects and place the object's values in the "tObjects"
    // member, then bind the object to the 2D texture target

    glGenTextures (nImages, tObjects);

    for (int nImage = 0; nImage < nImages; nImage++)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tObjects [nImage]);

        // This code loads the texture using the windows library's "BitmapFile" object
        BitmapFile texture;
        if (!texture.Read(tName[nImage]))
            complain("Couldn't read texture %s", tName);

        GLuint srcFormat, targFormat;
        // To Do
        // 
        // First decide which format the texture is.  If the texture has 4 bytes
        // per pixel then it should be an RGBA texture, if it is 3 bytes per pixel
        // then it is an RGB image.  Notice though that the byte order for the BitmatFile
        // object is reversed, so you need to take that into account in the "source" format

        if( texture.BytesPerPixel() == 3 )
        {
            srcFormat = GL_BGR;
            targFormat = GL_RGB;
        }
        else
        {
            srcFormat = GL_BGRA;
            targFormat = GL_RGBA;
        }

        // Then you need to set the unpack alignment to tell OpenGL about the structure 
        // of the data in the image and send the data to OpenGL.  If there are multiple files
        // then we are manually creating a mipmap here and you will use the "level" parameter
        // of glTexImage2D to tell OpenGL which mipmap level is being set.  The levels are 
        // set in the same order as they are stored in the image list.

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, targFormat, texture.Width(), texture.Height(), 0, srcFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.ImageData());

        glGenerateMipmap (GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    }
}
```